# Why is the variance used so often in statistics instead of other higher moments?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am learning statistics recently. By far, many statistical tests I saw, e.g. F-test, ANOVA, uses variance as their components. Hardly can I find any statistical test that uses third moment or even higher moments. It seems to me that statistics has a large favor in the second moment. In linear regression, we consider the sum of 'squared' residuals. In Ridge regression, we use $L^2$ norm to penalize the estimated coefficients.

Why is the second moment (or 'squared' or '$L^2$' norm) so ubiquitous in the statistical world?

Comment: $L^2$ is kind of a good space. For example, its norm comes from scalar product. So, in particular one can project its elements on a subspace or develop them in an orthogonal sum.

Comment: See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430365/there-is-a-nice-theory-of-quadratic-forms-how-about-cubic-forms-quartic-forms) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202732/higher-moments-what-are-they-good-for).

Comment: Many of those statistical tests are derived assuming normal observations/use the Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: @mr_e_man Thanks for the reference. I learnt a lot from the MO post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second moment is always non-negative, so one can optimize it (by making it small).  Can't do that with the third moment.

Also the second moment admits simple derivatives (leading to *linear* equations).

The second moment is simpler to compute than higher-orders.